# How to deploy WaveMaker project without runtimeLoader.js

Tags: javascript, html, wavemaker

WaveMaker is a powerful ajax based UI builder, but its JSON-RPC API standard is incompatible with our web service, which only has a RESTful API. As a result, we would like to design an UI without using any service using WaveMaker, and only extract part of its source code that runs on browser side (discarding all services)

Unfortunately, we can neither view or test the extracted code (all .html files show an empty page), a javascript reference in index.html is pointing to runtimeLoader.js, which we cannot find anywhere. So, is it possible to deploy the browser side code on a web container (not an application container like Tomcat) without runtimeLoader.js? If this is not possible, how do I change the source code so it can be tested without using WaveMaker?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having a java server in the mix, you could "import" REST calls to your API into the application. The XHR service (new in 6.5) targets JSON returning services. The 'Build-a-Service' does best with XML returning services. The browser would then call the WM java server, which in turn calls your REST services.

An easy way to get started with a WaveMaker client only app is to use the phonegap build option. This will build a zip file of a stand alone app. If you unzip that into say an apache served folder, you will render pages, etc. Note this build is targeted towards mobile devices via phonegap, so you will want to make adjustments if you are targeting desktop browsers.

Also, runtimeLoader.js can be found in the client runtime lib folder. e.g. /studio/lib/runtimeLoader.js of the installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've already tested phonegap build. But there must be some configuration problems that I didn't tried one by one. The landing page (index.html) cannot be run directly in Windows directory (probably because Windows file system uses a different slash). And publishing it takes longer than usual due to its sheer size.

Hope there is a step-by-step guide for a phonegap 'clean' deployment